# images load then disappear on devices in any browser in java

Tags: javascript, ipad, browser, tablet, image-loading

working in java,JSP,jQuery

other images and profile image loading and then disappears on any device like iPad or tablet in the browser but working fine on the desktop.

What might be the issue please help.

other images displaying in jquery data table. and profile image it is in simple way

ex: setting image and then getting it on jsp page.

```
session.setAttribute("photo", request.getContextPath() + "/file/" + profileImageUrl 
                                                                  + ".json");
```

Images appearing for the ipad os--> [7.0.1,7.1.1,8.4 (ipad2)], but not for 8.3 and 8.4(ipad mini).

For Android Os--> working for 4.4.2 Not for 5.1.1

```
I have plugin.js inside my project and if i remove it , it seems working(images are staying on page) fine but my whole project stop working. And if i comment any of the  *.js inside plugin.js then also project stops from working.
```

Comment: Please provide an example for us to debug.

Comment: @Rvervuurt I have plugin.js inside my project and if i remove it , it seems working(images are staying on page) fine but my whole project stop working. And if i comment any of the  *.js inside plugin.js then also project stops from working.